# Querying the queried result of array using AWS

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-appsync, aws-aurora-serverless, aws-pipeline

I have a situation where :

- In the first step I need to write a MySQL query from appsync, which returns an array of objects (of say n objects)
- In the second step, I need to query for every object in query 1's output, which in turn returns an array of objects (say m objects)
- In the third step, I need to create nm entries into a table.

Which AWS Service suits this problem?

I have tried two approaches, but nothing seems to work fine.

1st approach, using lambda where I wrote all the queries one after the other inside .then() but the in the output the queries are executing randomly even after using await.

2nd Approach, using pipeline resolvers.

I have tried creating a function for querying the first required output which is returning result (array of n objects as output).

Now I'm unable to write a query such that it executes for each of the object.

Can anyone suggest a better aws service for this problem or a working solution that could be possible with above approaches.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you show us ur lamda code=